# Flexbox 2 divs different height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How do I get this working in `flexbox`:

When the `red box` has more content than the `green box` (see my example) the
`green box` should not get the same height as the `red box` but only what's needed.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.border {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
}

.p-2 {
  padding: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="bg-red border p-2">
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>
    <p>content-red</p>

  </div>

  <div class="bg-green border p-2">
    <p>content-green</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How do I get that working with flexbox?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `align-items: flex-start;` on the element of class `.flex` :

```
.flex {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

We need to do this because the default value of align-items is stretch which make child elements take same height.

Comment: Wow thanks, but why is that?

Comment: @Jenssen because the default value of align-items is stretch

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_align-items.asp

Comment: @Jenssen Please upvote the answer if it worked for you :)

Comment: better add the explanation of the *why* within the answer

Comment: @TemaniAfif Done

Answer (score 0):

add `height:100%` to green box

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
}

.border {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

.bg-red {
  background: red;
}

.bg-green {
  background: green;
  height: 100%;
}

.p-2 {
   padding: 8px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="flex">
   <div class="bg-red border p-2">
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>
      <p>content-red</p>

   </div>
   
   <div class="bg-green border p-2">
      <p>content-green</p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, working both!

Comment: @Jenssen i don't agree with this solution as by adding height:100% you create another issue thus the height will be auto and you have the needed result ... is it logic for you that adding height:100% will decrease the height?

Comment: @Zuber check this : https://caniuse.com/#search=min-content

Comment: already checked @TemaniAfif

Comment: @Zuber so I guess you noticed that it's working only on chrome ;)

Comment: yes it is :( @TemaniAfif i should remove my edit